# Video camera crashes after latest(4.4.2) Samsung/OS update

Tags: android, android-camera, android-hardware

I am using custom camera in my application this works fine in jelly bean. Now after this Samsung Galaxy Tab OS update the custom camera is broken. I got this report from one of my friend i didn't saw that tablet. And i got crash report form `Carshylytics`.

My log report:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.x.y/com.x.y.tools.EnregistrementVideoStackActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to initialize media recorder
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2053)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:146)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1260)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4949)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1043)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:810)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to initialize media recorder
       at android.media.MediaRecorder.native_setup(MediaRecorder.java)
       at android.media.MediaRecorder.<init>(MediaRecorder.java:121)
       at com.x.y.tools.EnregistrementVideoStackActivity.<init>(EnregistrementVideoStackActivity.java:38)
       at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Class.java)
       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2044)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:146)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1260)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4949)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1043)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:810)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

And this error line is

```
public MediaRecorder mrec = new MediaRecorder();
```

Why it is happen have any idea? How can i solve this issue. I hope the camera code is not needed. But anyone want to see the code i can post here.

**EDIT:**

My EnregistrementVideoStackActivity class:

```
 public class EnregistrementVideoStackActivity extends Activity implements
        SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private SurfaceView surfaceView;
    public MediaRecorder mrec = new MediaRecorder();
    private Button startRecording = null;
    private Button stopRecording = null;
    File video;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private String output_path;

    boolean isActivityRestarting = false;

    Chronometer myChronometer;
    Boolean recording = false;

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            if (recording == false) {
                finish();
            } else {
                stopRecording();
            }
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        isActivityRestarting = true;
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (isActivityRestarting) {
            return;
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        /*getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);*/

        setContentView(R.layout.camera_surface);
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        output_path = intent.getStringExtra("path");

        startRecording = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonstart);
        stopRecording = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonstop);
        try {
            // This case can actually happen if the user opens and closes the
            // camera too frequently.
            // The problem is that we cannot really prevent this from happening
            // as the user can easily
            // get into a chain of activites and tries to escape using the back
            // button.
            // The most sensible solution would be to quit the entire EPostcard
            // flow once the picture is sent.
            mCamera = Camera.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Please restart device, camera error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            finish();
            return;
        }
        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_camera);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        myChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);

        startRecording.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                try {
                    startRecording();
                    myChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    myChronometer.start();

                    startRecording.setClickable(false);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.getMessage();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    mrec.release();
                }

            }
        });
        stopRecording.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                try {
                    stopRecording();
                    myChronometer.stop();
                    Intent intent = getIntent();
                    intent.putExtra("gallery", "viewed");
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.getMessage();
                }

            }
        });

        myChronometer
                .setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {

                    public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
                        long myElapsedMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
                                - myChronometer.getBase();
                        if (myElapsedMillis >= 120000) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Maximum Video limit reached",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            stopRecording();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.add(0, 0, 0, "StartRecording");
        menu.add(0, 1, 0, "StopRecording");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 0:
            try {
                startRecording();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                String message = e.getMessage();
                Log.e(null, "Problem Start" + message);
                mrec.release();
            }
            break;

        case 1: // GoToAllNotes
            mrec.stop();
            mrec.release();
            mrec = null;
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    protected void startRecording() throws IOException {
        recording = true;
        mrec = new MediaRecorder(); // Works well
        mCamera.unlock();
        mrec.setCamera(mCamera);
        mrec.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mrec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);

        mrec.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);

        mrec.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mrec.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        int width = 320;
        int height = 240;
        try {
            // Check what resolutions are supported by your camera
            List<Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();

            for (Size size : sizes) {

                Log.e("TAG", "Available resolution: " + size.width + " "
                        + size.height);
                width = size.width;
                height = size.height;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mrec.setVideoFrameRate(30);
        mrec.setVideoSize(width, height);
        mrec.setVideoEncodingBitRate(1700000);
        mrec.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
        mrec.setOutputFile(output_path);
        mrec.prepare();
        mrec.start();
    }

    protected void stopRecording() {
        try {
            Log.e("stop recording", "Stop recording");
            recording = false;
            mrec.stop();
            mrec.release();
            mCamera.release();
            // go out

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "New Video Observation Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception npe) {
            npe.printStackTrace();
        }
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();

    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        //
    }

    Parameters params;

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        if (!isActivityRestarting) {
            if (mCamera != null) {
                params = mCamera.getParameters();
                mCamera.setParameters(params);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Camera not available!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            if (mCamera != null) {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
                mCamera.release();
                mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
                mCamera = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (recording == false) {
            finish();
        } else {
            stopRecording();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please post the rest of the EnregistrementVideoStackActivity class

Comment: i dont know if this will solve anything, but you should initialize the media recorder in `OnCreate`. something like this: `public MediaRecorder mrec;
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (isActivityRestarting) {
            return;
        }
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
 

 mrec = new MediaRecorder();

//..`

Comment: What is the difference between declare inside of oncreate and global declaration ...

Comment: sometimes the context need to be created before. Initializing fields in the declaration, makes them to be created before the constructor of the class is called (so the constructor of Activity is not called, and the constructor of the context is not called yet)

Comment: If this is the case then how it is working in older versions

Comment: COuld be for many reasons, but As i said, i dont know if it will solve it, but trying it is easy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64001/discussion-between-amsheer-and-carlos-robles).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the error Because of Video sizes are not set. I solve this

```
int width = 320;
            int height = 240;
            try {
                //get the available sizes of the video
                List<Size> tmpList = getSupportedVideoSizes();

                final List<Size> sizeList = new Vector<Size>();

                // compare the apsect ratio of the candidate sizes against the
                // real ratio
                Double aspectRatio = (Double.valueOf(getWindowManager()
                        .getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()) / getWindowManager()
                        .getDefaultDisplay().getWidth());
                for (int i = tmpList.size() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                    Double tmpRatio = Double.valueOf(tmpList.get(i).height)
                            / tmpList.get(i).width;

                    if (Math.abs(aspectRatio - tmpRatio) < .15) {
                        width = tmpList.get(i).width;
                        height = tmpList.get(i).height;
                        sizeList.add(tmpList.get(i));
                    }
                }
                if (EnableLog.LOG_TAG) {
                    Log.e("tmpList", tmpList + "*");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

mrec.setVideoSize(width, height);

public List<Size> getSupportedVideoSizes() {
        if (params.getSupportedVideoSizes() != null) {
            return params.getSupportedVideoSizes();
        } else {
            // Video sizes may be null, which indicates that all the supported
            // preview sizes are supported for video recording.
            return params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        }
    }
```